# How to create symlink in windows server core 2012 R2

Tags: windows, symlink

On windows 7 machine I created a symlink using following command:

```
mklink <link_name> C:\test.txt
```

When I opened the link, it opened the text file which is expected behavior.
But when I do the same thing on windows server core it fails with,

```
class not registered
```